# Tooltips in Bootstrap are not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title" data-placement="left" href="#" alt="EMAIL">
  <img src="email-icon.png" width=100 height=100 >
</a>
```

I think I've tried everything including other posts on here.

I've added a script at the very start of my  section which goes as follows:

And I'm attempting to add a tooltip to my button which looks like this:

And it does absolutely nothing. I've added all the relevant .js files, and the only thing I can think of is that maybe the fact that I'm using bootswatch CSS could be messing it up? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title" data-placement="left" href="#" alt="EMAIL">
  <img src="email-icon.png" width=100 height=100 >
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct but The default left side position hiding show did not display. Hope this helps you.

```js
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Hooray!">Hover over me</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Title" data-placement="left" href="#" alt="EMAIL">
                <img src="email-icon.png" width=100 height=100 >
            </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 4 this is easier. See example below.

Reference link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/tooltips/#examples

You are using bootstrap 3 so must follow necessary supported standards accordingly to that version.

```js
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
```

```html
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
```